# JS OR statement just not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked a million times but I've gone through just about every method suggested in other threads and cannot seem to figure out why the `OR` statement in my `IF` is not working. And would like some explanation as to how to use the `OR` function if I am doing this completely wrong.

I have the following code

```
if((a != 'error') || (a != 'stay')) {
    //Do something here
}
```

And regardless if the a is `error` or `stay` the code is being executed anyway

I have also tried

```
if((!a == 'error') || (!a == 'stay')) {
    //Do something here
}
```

And without brackets, but noting seems to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that first statement is always true - if you think about it, because if a is error it's not stay and vice versa, so either the first comparison OR the second is true, that's how OR works - perhaps you wanted `&&` (AND)

Comment: You probably meant `if(!(a == 'error' || a == 'stay'))` instead of negating `a`

Comment: I guarantee you, the OR statement **is** working, you are just not saying what you want to say (what you think you're saying).  Describe, in words, what you are trying to test for. You want to "Do something here" when `a` is not `error` and a is not `stay` (?)  You want to "Do something here" when `a` is either `error` or it's `stay` (?) \[and, by the way, your question has nothing to do with jquery]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is a tautology. It's true no matter what the value of a is. If a is 'error' then a is not 'stay' and vice versa. It seems like what you want is

```
if (a != 'error' && a != 'stay') { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I see, I assumed that if I said && the if would only be fired if it wasn't error AND wasn't stay, so that if it were either one it would still go through because the other statement would return false

Comment: I should have asked before answering, but what exactly do you expect it to do, if not what you just described?

Answer (score -1):

You are including the (!) sign together in the brackets which is an error and will not make the logical operator work. You need to put the (!) sign outside and before the bracket. Check this code below for more clarity.

```
var a = "hello";
var b = "stay";
var c = "error";
if(!(a == 'error') || !(a == 'stay')) {
console.log("Hello");
};
```

for best practice, you should have it like this

```
var a = "hello";
var b = "stay";
var c = "error";
if(!(a == 'error' || a == 'stay')) {
console.log("Hello");
};
```

Comment: @DanielBeck how do you mean?

Comment: I mean they don't do the same thing.  The first one will always log "Hello". The second one will log "Hello" for any value of `a` except 'error' or 'stay'.